# Performing a keyword search across all open excel workbooks VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working on a lot of Excel VBA Macros codes and have achieved a lot. I've run into an issue, where I wish to perform a search for a keyword that may be available in one of the open Excel Workbooks, like - ABC12345 and I want the criteria to be met if "ABC" is found in cell B2.

My code so far:

```
Sub ABC_Upload()
Sheets("Add File Here").Select
If IsEmpty(Range("A1")) Then
  Worksheets("Master Mapper").Activate

  Dim answerABC As Integer
answerABC = MsgBox("Please check the Data Sheet. No value found in first row! Do you wish to find XYZ file in open workbooks and start process?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Review & Proceed")
If answerABC = vbYes Then

    'Starts here
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wBook As Workbook
    Dim XYZFound As Range
    Dim xFound As Boolean
    Dim lngLastRow2 As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each wBook In Application.Workbooks
        For Each wSheet In wBook.Worksheets
            Set XYZFound = Nothing
            Set XYZFound = wSheet.Cells.Find(What:="ABC", After:=wSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
            'Set XYZFound = wSheet.Cells.Find(What:="BIC", After:=wSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

            'XYZFound.Cells.Select
            If Not XYZFound Is Nothing Then
                xFound = True
                Application.Goto XYZFound, True
            'Rows(1, 2).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            lngLastRow2 = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            Range("A1:E" & lngLastRow2).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Add File Here").Activate
            Range("A1").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            End If

        Next wSheet
        If xFound Then Exit For
        Next wBook

If XYZFound Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "No open file for XYZ Meetings Found. Make sure the most recent XYZ Excel WB is open!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
Exit Sub
End If
    'Ends Here

Sheets("Add File Here").Select
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:=";", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:=":", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:=",", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="(", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:=")", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="{", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="}", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="[", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="]", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="~+", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="~*", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="~?", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="_", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:=".", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="'", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="\", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="/", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:=".", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="@", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:=Chr(34), Replacement:=""

Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("C1").Value = "Client ID"
Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("D1").Value = "Client Name"
Columns("E:E").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("E1").Value = "Planner Name"
Columns("I:I").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("I1").Value = "External System Name"
Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    'Set the range in column A you want to loop through
    Set rng = Range("B2:B100")
    For Each cell In rng
        'test if cell is empty
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            'write to adjacent cell
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Company ID"
        End If
    Next
Dim rngC As Range
    Dim Ci As Long

    'Set the range in column A you want to loop through
    Set rngC = Range("C2:C100")
    For Each cell In rngC
        'test if cell is empty
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            'write to adjacent cell
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Company"
        End If
    Next
Dim rngP As Range
    Dim Pi As Long

    'Set the range in column A you want to loop through
    Set rngP = Range("D2:D100")
    For Each cell In rngP
        'test if cell is empty
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            'write to adjacent cell
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "NA"
        End If
    Next
Dim rnEP As Range
    Dim Ei As Long

    'Set the range in column A you want to loop through
    Set rngE = Range("H2:H100")
    For Each cell In rngE
        'test if cell is empty
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            'write to adjacent cell
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Company"
        End If
    Next
'MsgBox "File has been formatted for XYZ and is ready for MMS upload.", vbOKOnly
Dim answer As Integer
answer = MsgBox("Temporary File Prepared for XYZ. Do you wish to proceed with MMS_NewMtgs file creation?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Review & Proceed")
If answer = vbYes Then
    Call Prepare_OutputFile
Else
    MsgBox "Output file not created!! Please select - Click to create MMS Formatted File from Master Mapper.", vbOKOnly
End If
End If
End If
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  Also,  removing the on error resume next is often helpful for debugging, as it will hide the actual source of any errors...

Comment: You set the answer from MsgBox to `answerABC`, but in `If` statement you check `answerBICL`. Is that "typo"?

Comment: You have to make sure you qualify all ranges with their expected workbook/worksheet.  Whenever you have `Range(Cells(), Cells())`, it's going to use the range and cells from the **ActiveWorkbook / Worksheet`.  You need to do like, `wBook.wSheet.Cells(Rows.Count,"B").End(xlUp).Row` or else it's going to get the last row from the activebook/sheet. If you want that, then please be explicit still.  (Note that `Rows.Count` doesn't necessarily need the sheet/book reference, since that's the same (assumedly) for all worksheets.)

Comment: Include `Option Explicit` as the first line of every code module.  That will then tell you as soon as you try to use undeclared variables in your code, and point you straight to the undefined `answerBICL` that @EganWolf mentioned.

Comment: @EganWolf So sorry, answerBICL is a typo!

Comment: @nwhaught the code works and copies the data that I want, but after copying it gives me the "No open file for ABC Found. Make sure the most recent ABC Excel WB is open!" message.

Comment: @YowE3K let me try adding that and see if it helps! Thanks.

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Place text cursor somewhere within the code at press F8 to run macro line by line. You can check values of your variables at any time and it should help you find a problem.

Comment: @EganWolf I tried that too!

Comment: @AkshaySachdev Adding `Option Explicit` won't fix the problem - it just causes VBA to refuse to compile until you fix the problem (and in your case will highlight the fact that you are using a variable `answerBICL` when you probably meant to use `answerABC`).

Comment: `Columns("C:E").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove` ... inserts three columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can shorten the search lines by using this:

```
    Columns("A").Replace ";", ""
    Columns("A").Replace ":", ""
    Columns("A").Replace ",", ""
    Columns("A").Replace "(", ""
    Columns("A").Replace ")", ""
    Columns("A").Replace "{", ""
                 . 
                 . 
                 . 
                 .
```

this is an example of a good reason to use the *With* command

```
    With Columns("A")
        .Replace ";", ""
        .Replace ":", ""
        .Replace ",", ""
        .Replace "(", ""
        .Replace ")", ""
        .Replace "{", ""
                 . 
                 . 
                 . 
    End With
```

or this:

```
    Dim badText As Variant
    For Each badText In Array(";", ":", ",", _
                               "(", ")", "{", "}", "[", "]", _
                               "~+", "~*", "~?", "_", ".", _
                               "'", "\", "/", "@", """")       ' chr(34) = " (quote), in VBA string it must be escaped by doubling it up

        Columns("A").Replace badText, ""
    Next badText
```

another place to simplify:

the two range content checks where you put the text "Company" beside each non-empty cell

```
Set rngC = Range("C2:C100")
For Each cell In rngC
         .
         .
Set rngE = Range("H2:H100")
For Each cell In rngE
         .
```

the two *For* loops can be combined into one that starts with this line:

```
For Each cell In Range("C2:C100, H2:H100")
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from what @nwhaught said, there is a problem in `If xFound = 1 Then Exit For`. Your `xFound` is declared as `Boolean` and despite you set a value of `1` (one) to it, the real value is `True`. Now, for VBA `True` is not equal `1` and your `If` condition is always `False`. The value of `True` in VBA is `-1`, but you don't need this. Just use `If xFound Then Exit For`, as checking a value of boolean is enough, there's no need to compare it with another boolean.

Comment: I've edited and shared my final code which is still giving me the same issue! I know its a very poorly done code, but at the end all I want is it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you don't exit your inner for loop in time.  You exit the outer for after processing all of the sheets, which is setting XYZfound back to nothing.

If you only need to find this thing once, then move your 'exit for' up a couple of lines, and terminate the loop before processing the next sheet in the workbook.

Comment: That is what is happening. If I have multiple excel workbooks open, it does find the right sheet, copy as required but then gives me the message! I'm literally pulling out my hair and nothing really is working out!

Comment: It's processing all the sheets in the workbook, regardless of whether or not it found the value. Each sheet that gets processed resets xyz to nothing,  which is happening after the value is found.

Comment: I'll tell you my dilemma, I get a file where column B has values like ABC12345. I'm looking to have my Find condition to look for value "ABC" in cell B2. If it's there, continue with the process, if not give the Message declared at end..

Set rFound = wSheet.Cells.Find(What:="ABC ", After:=wSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)

Comment: I've edited and shared my final code which is still giving me the same issue! I know its a very poorly done code, but at the end all I want is it to work!

Comment: Awesome! If you've got it working,  please click on the check to accept the answer, and/ or upvote...